# Problems with BufferedImage SubImages

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I am currently trying to get my java program to load separate sprites from a sprite sheet. When I try to get The yellow square in this sprite sheet
[image: The yellow square in this sprite sheet].
However, what I get is this
[image: this].

Prior to this I was able to load and render an entire PNG file without problems, and I am unsure the reason for it not working. I put snippets of code that I use to load images, render images, and getting the subimage. I'm still somewhat new to java, so I'm not sure if there is a better solution to this

```
//The code I use to load a PNG as a BufferedImage
public BufferedImage loadImage(String path) {
    try {
      BufferedImage loadedImage = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(path));
      BufferedImage formattedImage = new BufferedImage(loadedImage.getWidth(), loadedImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
      formattedImage.getGraphics().drawImage(loadedImage, 0, 0, null);
      return formattedImage;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }


    //The code I use to render an image onto the screen
    public void renderImage(BufferedImage image, int xpos, int ypos) {
      int[] imgpixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

      for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
          if (!(x + xpos > getScreenWidth() - 1) && !(y + ypos > getScreenHeight() - 1) && !(x + xpos < 0) && !(y + ypos < 0)) {
            pixels[(x + xpos) + (y + ypos) * getScreenWidth()] = imgpixels[x + y * image.getWidth()];
          }
        }
      }
    }

    //the code I used to get the subimage
    public BufferedImage getImage(int index) {
      int i = index % (row * col);
      int x = tileX * (i % col);
      int y = tileY * (i % row);
      return spriteSheet.getSubimage(x, y, tileX, tileY);
      //still does the same thing if I were to put in spriteSheet.getSubimage(0, 0, 16, 16)
    }
```

Comment: What's `titleX` and `titleY`?

Comment: tileX and tileY is the size of the tile

Comment: Okay, so, after rebuilding some of the missing code, I've verified that, mostly, the `subImage` routine works, so I guess the problem is in the rendering, but since a lot of that is missing, I guess it's just guess work

Comment: it would be better to have a [mcve] - posted code is missing a lot (e.g. `pixels`, ...) And sure not the best to do pixel manipulation (kind of assuming how the pixels are stored in the raster). I also suspect the logic for calculating `x` and `y` in `getImage`, modulo `row` and `col` is very strange (not the main problem of question)

Comment: Make sure your PNG is really of type `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB` and not `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`. If the alpha byte isn't expected, the sub image won't account for it and you'll get weird offsets.

Comment: In reality I believe it should be **something like this**: `spriteSheet.getSubimage((column * 16) - 16, (row * 16) - 16, 16, 16);` otherwise: `spriteSheet.getSubimage((1 * 16) - 16, (1 * 16) - 16, 16, 16);`.

Comment: Why are you transferring pixels from one array to another in the first place? Is there any reason to not use one of the (many!) `drawImage` methods directly? (Note that there are versions that dedicatedly can draw *portion* (i.e. one sprite) of a larger image...)